# Brackets appearing when bot sends reply (discord, python)

Tags: python, discord, bots

I'm making a 8ball bot on discord -- out of boredom, but that's besides the point. Whenever I get it to send the reply, brackets appear where the answer should just be plain, anyone knows how to fix it?

This is my code

````
@bot.command(name='8ball', help='Gives the answer to any of your questions')
async def quotelist(ctx):
    quotelist = [
        'As I see it, yes.',
        'Ask again later.',
        'Better not tell you now.',
        'Cannot predict now.',
        'Concentrate and ask again.',
        'Don\'t count on it.',
        'It is certain.',
        'It is decided so.',
    ]
    
    response = random.choices(quotelist)
    await ctx.send(response)

bot.run("Nxxx")```
````

Answer (score 2):

`random.choices` returns a list of choices, then discord.py converts the list to a string, which is where the brackets come from. You're looking for `random.choice` (note the lack of an s), which returns only one element from the list.

Comment: So how do I fix it, @Aplet123

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out by removing the s.